# AngularJS image upload with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have done this before, but right now it just doesn't work and I CAN'T figure out what in the world is wrong.

I am trying to upload an image with Angularjs, by passing it to a PHP file. But for some reason, the image does not get passed to the PHP file.

My form:

```
    <form ng-submit="addImage()" id="addImageForm" class="collapse">

         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="newImage">Choose image</label><br>
             <input type="file" file-input="files" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)">
         </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">

    </form>
```

My angularjs directive which seems to be working just fine:

```
//File upload
app.directive("fileInput", function ($parse) {
return{
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on("change", function (event) {
            var files = event.target.files;
            console.log(files[0].name);
            $parse(attrs.fileInput).assign($scope, element[0].files);
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    }
};
});
```

My controller:

```
//Get image name
$scope.setFile = function (element) {
    $scope.$apply(function ($scope) {
        $scope.theFile = element.files[0];
    });
};

//Upload image
$scope.addImage = function () {
    var form_data = new FormData();

    angular.forEach($scope.files, function (file) {
        form_data.append('file', file);
    });

    $http.post(
            "handlers/add_image.php",
            form_data,
            {transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 'Process-Data': false}}
    ).success(function (response) {
        $scope.response = response;

    });
};
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES){
echo "There is a file!";
}else{
echo "There is no file";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="file" file-input="files" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)">
```

To :

```
<input type="file" name="files" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)">
```

A nice [example here](https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/11208/simple-image-upload-using-angularjsphp.html)

Comment: Didn't change anything :-(

Comment: Use code in lik I gave in answer, and make sure if angular.js exist in your file.